# How to pass a GET Variable to a form

Tags: php, forms

I have three pages. One of which there is a list of texts the user can select. Upon clicking on one of the texts they will be redirected to another page by using:

```
<a href='second.php?text=whatever>Whatever</a>
```

A page where they will input the username they wish to send those texts to - using forms. I wish to proceed to the third page with those two variable - texts and username. I only manage to proceed to third page with username only.

I am getting third.php?username=inputtedUsername.
I want to get third.php?username=inputtedUsername&&text=whatever.
I am aware that I can do by storing the text to a SESSION on page two and than transfer it over to third page.

I wish to know if there is another secure way to do this - maybe something needed to be changed in the form action=thirdpage.php? I dont know. Thank you. ö.ö.

Solved: After reading comments and answer, the thing I need was type=hidden. It is now working on my part. Thanks everyone for helping me. :).

Comment: Have you tried including the text as an `<input type=hidden ...>` field on the second page?

Comment: try adding this inside your page 2 form <input type="hidden" name="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['text'] ?>">

Comment: `'second.php?text=whatever'`? you can't just put whatever to the text, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Why do you want it to be secure? What type of content is this?

Comment: Thank everyone for helping me. So the thing I need was type=hidden. It worked on my part. :).

Answer (score 0):

`'second.php?text=whatever'`? You can't just put whatever to the text, you are doing it wrong. Try this.

**firstpage.php**

```
<?php
    $whatever = 'Tom & Jerry, 1 + 2 = 3';
    echo '<a href="secondpage.php?text=' . base64_encode($whatever) . '">' . $whatever . '</a>';
?>
```

**secondpage.php**

```
<form action="thirdpage.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="text" value="<?php echo base64_decode($_GET['text']); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**thirdpage.php**

```
<?php
    echo 'Username: ' . $_POST['username'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Text: ' . $_POST['text']; 
?>
```